# officejs direct database connection

Tags: excel, office-js

I am working on a Office.js Add-in for Excel.  I want to connect directly to a database, is this possible?

The obvious why is to use a web service, but I prefer to bypass this approach.  I tried using ActiveX object without success.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the *Components of an Office Add-in* section of [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins), an Office (web) Add-in is made up of a XML configuration file (the manifest) and a web application. You can build the web application using the technology of your choice and design it to do any of the things that a typical web application can do, including things like read from a database, call a web service, etc.

For example, common (database-related) scenarios for an Excel add-in might include:

- Retrieve data from a database and then use the [Excel JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-reference-overview) to write that data to the workbook.
- Use the [Excel JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-reference-overview) to read data from the workbook and then save that data to a database.

When it comes to reading data from and writing data to a database from your Excel add-in, you can accomplish that just as you would in any other web application with the language/platform of your choice.